Is there a way to pass an image to the Microsoft snipping tool, have it perform text extraction, and return that extract
I'm working on something that uses OCR for fun.  I'm currently using PyTesseract, and it has a very high error rate, so I built a user validation function so the ingested text could be verified.  As I was testing different things I got tired of hand typing one of the lines that PyTesseract would constantly get wrong, so I took a snip and used the text extraction function in the snipping tool.  It had 100% accuracy.
That got me thinking, that if I could just find a way to get python to invoke the snipping tool, it would A) increase the accuracy of the OCR.  B) remove the need to have people who use this thing install Tesseract-OCR so their local python could run the code.
I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it though, or if it is even possible.  I read something on here about how to take a screenshot within PowerShell, but that's only half of my problem.  Any help would be great.
The code I have currently is located on https://github.com/MElse1/Puzzle-Solving/blob/e591a77af27b7f7325b08edb725e12f31cc0f0c9/Word%20Search%20Solver/PyTesseract%20testing.py it's convoluted and probably badly done, but it gets the job done even if it's very inaccurate due to the OCR solution.
Since I linked my github, this isn't for anything serious, it's just a way to get better with programming logic in a way that's fun for me.  This solution is ultimately to solve word searches.  I have the logical part of the program down elsewhere in my github, but I thought it would be cool to use OCR to build the lists to search for the words.

It seems that this isn't supported: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/snipping-tools-text-actions-via-command-line/4a36489c-5142-424d-9323-e7e714eff780

I suspect that Snipping tool just uses the build in OCR functionality in Windows. You can use the OCR classes (which reside in the UWP/WinRT libraries which come with windows but are NOT trivial to use. I do have working samples on how to do this in Powershell)

Here is a sample on how to do OCR with Powershell (since you also tagged this as Powershell) using only libraries which are built into Windows (Windows 8 and higher have these built in).
You can modify this to get the result as a string so you can use it in python.
<#
    OCR sample using the built in WinRT API
#>

# FilePath of the image
$FilePath = "C:\test\OCRTestImage.png"

# OCR Language
$Language = 'en-us'

# assembly with the WindowsRT exention methods we need
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime

# load the RT assemblies we need
[void][Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow,Windows.UI.Core,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
[void][Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine,Windows.Media.Ocr,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
[void][Windows.Storage.StorageFile,Windows.Storage,ContentType=WindowsRunTime]
[void][Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder,Windows.Graphics.Imaging,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]

# get the AsTask generic extension method with the signature we need
$asTaskGeneric = ([System.WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions].GetMethods() | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'AsTask' -and $_.GetParameters().Count -eq 1 -and $_.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.Name -eq 'IAsyncOperation`1' })[0]

# Load the file
$StorageFileAsync = [Windows.Storage.StorageFile]::GetFileFromPathAsync($FilePath)
$StorageFile = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod([Windows.Storage.StorageFile]).Invoke($null, $StorageFileAsync).Result

# convert file to a stream
$StreamAsync = $StorageFile.OpenReadAsync()
$Stream = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod([Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType]).Invoke($null, $StreamAsync).Result

# And convert this to a bitmap => we'll have to create a softwareBitmap
$BitmapDecoderAsync = [Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder]::CreateAsync($Stream)
$BitMap = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod([Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder]).Invoke($null, $BitmapDecoderAsync).Result
$SoftwareBitmapAsync = $BitMap.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync()
$SoftwareBitmap = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod([Windows.Graphics.Imaging.SoftwareBitmap]).Invoke($null, $SoftwareBitmapAsync).Result


# OCR stuff => here we do the actual OCR stuff
# Create the OCR Engine object
$OCR = [Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine]::TryCreateFromLanguage($Language)
# Do the actual recognition
$OCRResultAsync = $OCR.RecognizeAsync($SoftwareBitmap)
$OCRResult = $asTaskGeneric.MakeGenericMethod([Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrResult]).Invoke($null, $OCRResultAsync).Result

# output the result
$OCRResult

In short I load the UWP/RT libraries, get the method signature of the extension method which is used to unwrap the iasync calls and after that it's just calling the methods and unwrapping the results.

This is awesome, however when I use the snipping tool text actions, the output I get is
SELBERTBEORMEBSR MEOFFHANDEDLYKOH OGCVISMROTSGCTAI OOUIRMIDCIOIAPHY B S SNPAS ANNKVRSK S VPTEHSOSEEESKCED DEGGAHGSVLSPUAEU SLLABEYEEMPLTRHS TKSRPTNXUHIALACI FONSEVIECEDNUBDP AOOMMISPLAYEDOIE RKCKNUTSSLLRAWSC CSIAMMIPBELDPECA GNIDLOCSTRSAIDSC
Which, aside from a couple weird spaces on line 5, is 100% correct. When I ran your code I got "s M o VI o Cl B V D s T Cl F VI A R c c E E c o s E L K o o K S L s T L S N o c B N E A R s M K A D E F R P H A B N M L H S A s H T o T A M S o c Y N S T

There's more after that, but I'm at the character limit for a comment, and powershell just ". . ."s the rest. I know how to get it to python from a PS1 if I have to, but I haven't yet because the results are off, worse than PyTesseract. When I first glanced at it, I thought it was reading top to bottom, then right to left, then you get to the VI and I'm not sure where that came from. So the follow on questions are "is there a way to increase the fidelity within the powershell example you posted", and "Is there a way to control the order it reads the text"

Also to be clear, I really appreciate your help, and I'm not trying to sound ungrateful.  I'm definitely putting that snippet into my own journal of solutions to problems I haven't found yet.  The comments in the code make it easy to see what each section is doing, but I fear I don't really understand how each section is doing what it's doing to be able to answer the questions in my second comment.  Also, I tried really hard to get the snipping tool output to present as grid on these comments, but I keeps dropping my newline characters.

@JohnnyBravo are you using the correct language code for the language you want to use? In my sample I've set it to en-us, but you might need a different language. Also, the Powershell script outputs a complete object (the result is in the "Text" property, but the "Lines" property contains an overview of all the lines). Unfortunately there are no settings which you can make for the built-in OCR engine using the WinRT libraries.

It's a word search, so it's going to be scanning a grid of random letters, I then have a python script that makes a list of lists with those letters, and then searches through those lists using indexing for a list of words.  So I'm not sure if the language is really important since I'm just wanting it to read the text from a picture without any kind of logical attempts to make sense of it.   I accepted your answer, I think that's probably as close to the intended solution I can get.
